# Creating web service app for enterprise Java vs C++?

Tags: java, c++, web-services, service, enterprise

So we want to develop a service app (web Service with post/get API). What is language to go for secure, fast, enterprise app for about 2000  employers to use with about 20~40 services for interacting with DB server (which in my case will be Oracle) Dev time a year Dev team of 3. All capable of righting C++ code as well as Java (so they will now them equally bad at the beginning of process)

Comment: We will not create any GUI just service side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is **not** what language to choose but which "architecture" or paradigm.
If you want/need to use SOAP then C++ might be fine, go and google for "gsoap". However I would recomend Java and REST as architecture paradigm, well we would need to know more what you really want to do. Perhaps some RMI or CORBA would be much easier. If you want to play with Java, Groovy or Scala (all languages run on the Java JVM), then google for "restlet".

Best Regards

Angelo

Comment: Your answer seems subjective may I ask for reference to support your statement please?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely java! You might want to check the jee6 tutorial on JAX-WS to get an idea of how web services are created using enterprise java (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

This will also guide you on how to do it using the [netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org) IDE (http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You'd be masochistic to try this with C++! Definitely Java, J2EE whatever (look at various technologies from groups such as JBoss). The development process will be significantly faster using these existing technologies than writing your own...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Java / Netbeans combination.

Netbeans has a number of tools which makes web service development easy.

Good overview [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/intro-ws.html).

Netbeans allows full use of JAX WS and Metro and is integrated with Glassfish and Tomcat servers (part of Netbeans download) so you can get up to speed really quickly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either C++ or Java depending what you're implementing. To see an example on C++ check out this great post by IBM Engineers: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-xml-rpc/